# A Flutter apps IP rights

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been developing a Flutter app for the past 11 months, in total it uses about 50 different packages/plugins too. I know the Flutter comes with a license and all the packages have licenses too but I'm not sure how IP of the app, or particular parts of the app, works in practise.

I think (although please correct me if I'm wrong) that I can say I don't own the IP for a `Row`, `Column` or `ListTile` widget but do own the IP for the `Dashboard` widget itself. Even though it uses many `Row`s or `Column`s, the way they are used together (and with other packages) has been created by me. Could that then be extrapolated out to say the company I work for own the IP to the app and how it functions?

For example, is it similar to Microsoft Office Word? A Word user doesn't own the IP for Word but they would own the IP for the document they create on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrote it, and it wasn't for hire or given away, it's still yours.

Almost everything you download from Google is under a liberal license.  Most of the things in the pub have a similar generous license.  If you upload something to the pub or put it on a repo like github, you set the license as you wish.

Edit: Legal disclaimer... it might be different where you live.  Talk to an IP lawyer if you're unsure.